# Recommended current 22.04 way to forward app's GUI Wayland to Wayland?

Tags: ssh, wayland

I used ssh -X in 16.04. Since being both local & remote 22.04 Wayland, there is no hit with *wayland* keyword search in ssh nor sshd manuals. I have Xwayland installed on each end. I get this error after I connect with ssh or ssh -X:

```
gedit&
[1] 27111
me@remote:~$ 
(gedit:27111): dbind-WARNING **: 14:35:14.547: Couldn't register with accessibility bus:
 Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply,
  the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired,
  or the network connection was broken.
```

I believe this is related to X11 being replaced with Wayland because ssh -X stands for enable X11 forwarding, but revert 22.04 to Xorg as advised around the web or downgrade to 16.04 I'd rather like not.

Please what is the new way ? Many thanks.

[EDIT] I checked with Graham's advice below but this made no difference (both remote & local sessions were/are Wayland)

[EDIT 2023/12] @ændrük, this post (17.10) was somewhat old since we use 22.04. Since my own post here (this very one), I only reached to get a remote GUI by using RDP :-)

Comment: log out and then back in again selecting wayland as the DE perhaps to test? [edit] your question with the result.

Comment: 16.04 is long gone as will be 18.04 in a few weeks. So neither of these should be considered.

Comment: Also the title is making no sense. Nothing in the question seems to match what ever you were trying to say with the title.

Comment: @David It makes total sense. The OP provides the background (that they have successfully used ssh -X) over the years from 2016 to forward graphical applications from one system to another. Their problem is that they are now on Wayland, and have not found any successful methods for achieving the same goal (forwarding graphical applications from one machine to another) when using Wayland instead of X.

Comment: I've not tried this as I don't use Wayland, but there's a suggestion elsewhere that this comment (waypipe) on reddit works. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/posuyb/kde_is_hiring_a_contractor_to_improve_hardware/hd1c2fq/?context=3

Comment: Wayland is, unless X11, not designed to forward graphical applications over a network. That is a deliberate decision for security, so by design, that cannot work. Use a remote desktop application instead.

Comment: @vanadium, this advice has a prohibitive prerequisite : I must be loged-in first. Caught22

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how does X11 forwarding with Ubuntu 17.10/Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981683/how-does-x11-forwarding-with-ubuntu-17-10-wayland)